# Exporting from MS access to Oracle - different schemas

Tags: vba, oracle, ms-access

I'm trying to use DoCmd.TransferDatabase to export a table from MS access to a schema other than the one I'm using to run the procedure in MS Access.

The reason I'm hoping to use this method is because from my experience, this is the fastest way to export.
I know that I can use a pass through query but I think it will slow me down.

How do I specify the schema into which I'm exporting?

here's what i'm doing currently

```
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC", NewConnect, acTable, MatchNewTable, CurProjectName & "_MATCHTMP", False, True
```

Comment: In place of `tableName` you'd likely use `schemaName.tableName` Difficult to say since you're not showing any code.

Comment: i edited the post. i tried that, still goes into the other schema and is named schema_tablename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I specify the schema into which I'm exporting?

You can't. You must link that table (again) using the schema you wish to export to. The (new) linked table can (re)named pretty much as you like.

Comment: Thank you. So what would you suggest considering that I cannot use that schema? This app will be used by others that login through their schema and I can't make them login through mine

Comment: You might be able to create a schema common (accessible) for all users ...

Comment: Not an option, unfortunately. Can I use a pass through query and do SELECT INTO?

Comment: I would expect _no_. I guess that missing granted rights to schemas are designed not to be circumvented. However, I don't know about the inner working of an Oracle database, so I would consult your db admin about what options you may have.